# how to display a 8bit 256x256 array in c/matlab?

Tags: c, image, matlab, rgb, 8-bit

i have an array in c:

```
unsigned char image_in[256*256] = {
     72,  57,  55,  67,  79,  58,  52,  72,  96,  81,  72,  76,  93, 107,  91,  84,  95,  66,....IT GOES ON AND ON 256x256.....}
```

each value is the 8bit rgb of the indexed pixel.

now the question is how do i show this picture? i can use C or matlab or whatever..

Comment: If all you want to do is display this image once, I suggest you write it to a file using the very simple [PNM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnm.html) format and then use (mostly) any image viewer.

Comment: write it to file in what format exactly? without ','? with any special header?

Comment: PNM files are useful because they have a simple format. The header is simple, the contents are structured in a simple manner. Check the link to get to know the format: [PNM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnm.html)

Comment: you want to show this image within the program where it's defined, or you just want to see it? and you can copy the values and paste somewhere else?

Comment: i can put it wherever i want. just wanna see the pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wops, the question is really not well formulated - there are many missing details, like: do you require a greyscale/RGB image? Do you want to do this programmatically (namely from your C-code), or just a quick one-time snapshot? Can you copy the values to some *.csv file or to a Matlab script (see Casliho's comment)?

If you just want to show the image as grayscale in Matlab, call the [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) function:

```
m = randint(256,256,256); % This creates a random 256x256 array of integers - replace with your values
imshow(m);                % This creates a greyscale image
```

From the plot object you will be able to export the image to many formats (*.jpg, *.png etc.)

Comment: thanks for the reply, the file is an RGB file 8bit. each value is a pixel (a 8bit represent the RGB within this pixel). imshow() in matlab  doesent work for me.

Comment: @Wops - imshow can display RGB. You simply make the input a 256x256x3 array. See the documentation.